# What is the relationship between natbib, apacite package, and apa document class?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, apa-style

This is the first time I have to submit to a journal and need to reformat my bibliography according to APA guidelines.

This leaves me very confused since there seem to be multiple ways to do the same thing:

1. Use `natbib` and `\bibliographystyle{apa}`
2. Use `natbib` and `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`
3. Use package `apacite`. How is this different from `natbib`? Apparently I also need to specify `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` even though I have already loaded the package `apacite`. Plus, I can also load `natbib` through `apacite`!?
4. The document class `apa6`. I understand that this formats the entire article, not just the bibliography. But as an option to this document class, I can load `natbib` as well?

I think my problem is that I'm only taught in simplistic terms, i.e. use `natbib` for your bibliography, without having a systematic understanding of how the process of creating a bibliography works. Could anyone please explain?

Answer (score 107):

These are good questions.

First let's distinguish a bibliography style from what I will call a  "citation package".  A bibliography style is a set of directives that tells `bibtex` how to format the entries of your bibliography.  It is (somewhat) independent of the citation package you use, although not completely.  Bibliography styles are written in the BibTeX stack language, and in your TeX distribution have the extension `.bst`.

So anything you supply as the style to a `\bibliographystyle{}` command is a `.bst` file.

### APA style bibliography styles

As you have noticed, there are a few of these that purport to do APA style bibliographies:

- `apa.bst`
- `apalike.bst`
- `apacite.bst`

What are each of these?

Both the `apalike` and `apa` bibliography styles are  old implementations of a style approximating (but not strictly speaking conforming to) the APA style. They're probably fine to use for a paper for a course where you are told to use APA style references, but they should not be used for submitting to an APA journal, or for a course where the professor really cares about the exact use of APA. (For example, I'm a linguist, and I'm happy to let my students use `apalike` if they want.)

The `apacite` style is a style that tries to conform as much as possible to actual APA requirements.  Since they change, it may not always be conforming, however, but it will be very close. The package is fairly up-to-date.  It should be used with the `apacite` package, and may additionally be used with `natbib`. (See below.)

### Citation packages

#### natbib

In addition to a bibliography style, you also typically need a package to manage citations, since the original TeX system was not terribly well set up for author-year style citations like the APA.  Here is where `natbib` comes in.

The `natbib` package provides a set of citation commands plus some other customizations that are especially made for author-year citations like APA uses.  Whereas plain LaTeX provides only a `\cite` command which has a single optional argument for a post-citation note, `natbib` defines two main citation commands `\citet` and `\citep`, each with two optional arguments: one for the pre-note and the other for the post-note.

These commands produce the two basic forms most author year systems need:

[image: natbib citations]

#### apacite

Now what does the `apacite` package do? It provides a different set of citation macros for doing citations:

[image: apacite citation macros]

But it also allows you to use the `natbib` citation commands by passing it the option `natbibapa`.

In addition to these citation commands, `apacite` provides a whole bunch of extra citation commands, including intext bibliography items (`\fullcite`) and even fancier things like citations with authors masked (useful for submitting to APA journals.)

Because of all of this functionality, and because the APA changes its requirements fairly often, the `apacite` package uses its own bibliography style, `apacite`, as mentioned above.

#### Can you mix and match?

If you want to use the `apacite` bibliography style, you should definitely load the `apacite` package.  There is no need to load the `natbib` package to use `apacite`, but you *can* load it if you prefer to use the standard `natbib` citation commands in addition to the extra commands that `apacite` provides. Provided you don't pass any options to `natbib` when you load it, it doesn't matter if you load both `apacite` with the `natbibapa` option and `natbib`, but it's not necessary.  But if you *do* want to use `natbib` with `apacite` you must pass the `natbibapa` option to `apacite`.

### The `apa6` document class

The `apa6` document class, as you note, is designed to format an article for submission to an APA journal (it can also simulate what the finished article will look like.)  So what it does is format things in the way the APA (in its infinite wisdom) prefers: double spacing, set margins, a specific title page and running head etc.

The class is agnostic about which method of citation you use, but it knows about `natbib` and `apacite` and these can be used as package options to the class.  It also allows you to use the `biblatex-apa` package as well.  I would *not* use this class unless you are submitting to an APA journal or you have a professor with an APA fetish who wants you to conform to the same requirements exactly.

### What about `biblatex-apa`?

One question you didn't ask, but I will add to the answer also, is that there is yet another way of dealing with citations which is quickly becoming the de facto standard, as many of us are actively using it: this is the combination of `biblatex` as a citation package plus `biber` as a replacement for `bibtex` to do sorting. For more information on this see:

- [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25702/2693)

There is a very good APA style for `biblatex`.  If you really need to use APA style, I would probably recommend using it over any of the others.  You would then not use a `\bibliographystyle` command nor would you load either `natbib` or `apacite` as packages, but instead would use `biblatex` with the package option `[style=apa]` instead.

See this question for a sample document using `biblatex-apa`.

[Perfect APA Style Bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/191404/2693)

### And finally some comments on what "APA style" means

Unfortunately the term "APA style" has come to have a bit of a generic meaning.  This is kind of like the way 'xerox' or 'kleenex' get used. These are officially brand names, but get used to mean the generic of the kind  in (N. American) English.

"APA style" is often used this way too, to mean a style is more or less like APA but depending on the journal may have minor differences.  But if they ask for APA style and you use the official one, you are certainly off to a good start.

The fact that a journal may want certain changes from the orthodox APA style is a strong reason for preferring the `biblatex` method over the `apacite` method.  It's notoriously hard to tweak `.bst` files, and the BibTeX language is not very easy to understand. But in `biblatex` all of the formatting is relatively accessible via regular LaTeX commands.  So if you are submitting to a non-APA journal, you would probably be better off using `biblatex` and modifying its default `authoryear` style  since it will be much easier to make changes to the standard `biblatex` styles than to a heavily customized style like `biblatex-apa` if needed. See the following question for details on how to make some common modifications.

- [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/2693)

Comment: 1) So the package `apacite` and `natbib` are both "citation package"? If so, is it possible to mix and match, i.e. use package `natbib` with `apacite.bst` without loading `\usepackage{apacite}`.  2) What's the difference between loading `natbib` via `apacite` and loading them both sequentially?

Comment: @Heisenberg I've added some clarifications.

Comment: Good questions with a good answer.

Comment: Very nice, parts of this should get into the wikibook, especially the last part. Kindly asking for permission here.

Comment: I found out that may be when mixing the packages `natbib` has to follow `apacite` (I think you could test it and add this info. Found out here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/482185/120578 )

Comment: @koleygr If you want to use `natbib` with `apacite` then you should just load `apacite` with the `natbibapa` option, and not load `natbib` directly at all.

Comment: @AlanMunn ... I just commented because my tests show that the order of loading matters and thus that you possibly could add to your already nice answer at the section of mixing that `natbib` has to be loaded after `apacite` (if for some reason someone want to mix them)... but this is just some tests in that question and I am sure you know more and I am possibly wrong

Comment: @AlanMunn I am told that the name of the authors should be in bold in the APA style. When I use `\usepackage{apacite}` with `\bibliographystyle{apacite}`, I cannot get that. How can I make the names of the authors bold?

Comment: @Hadij The APA style most definitely does *not* use bold author names. (See the part of my answer about how the term "APA style" has become somewhat generic.) But using `apacite` you can add `\renewcommand{\APACrefauthstyle}{\bfseries}` to your preamble after loading `apacite` to get bold author names.

Comment: The solution is brilliant. The journal I'm submitting enforced a variant of `apa` that it calls `theapa` which never compiled. But with `apacite` and `natbib`, it worked like a charm. Highly recommended if you happen to submit to JAIR.