# How can I make the apa6-document class NOT print a short title?

Tags: apa6

I am writing my master's thesis on TeXmaker. As for following the APA citation rules, I started using the apa6 document class. But even in the doc-mode, it still puts a short title (in capital letters) on top of every page, but I don't think that is appropriate in a master's thesis.
So my question is: how can I either erase that short title so it doesn't appear at all, or at least change it into normal letters? 
I tried `\renewcommand{\shorttitle}[1]{}` which I found in this forum, it seems to work for suppressing the abstract, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I would not use the `apa6` class at all. See [What is the difference between natbib, apacite package and apa6 document class?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263793/2693)

Comment: thank you @AlanMunn, that page helped me a lot! I think you are right, I will now use a more basic document class.

Answer (score 1):

I found a nice workaround: just leaving the `\shorttitle{}` -command empty helped. 
My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,doc]{apa6}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\title{title}
\author{C.Zet}
\affiliation{master's thesis}
\date{\today}
\shorttitle{ }
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. the doc still says "Running head:"

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `\thispagestyle{empty}` in the title section, in addition to `\shorttitle{ }`. This removes "Running head:" for me.