# APA Style citation. Allow author names outside parenthesis

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, apa-style

I need to use a minimal latex package that supports bibtex citations. I am currently using `apacite` package. but it only provides two types of citations. `\cite` and `\shortcite` both of which write the authors names and the year in parenthesis. I also need something that supports name of the authors outside the parenthesis (only year should be inside). How can I achieve that without using any custom templates? For example I would like to also use an additional command like `\newcite` that achieves that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{apacite}


\begin{document}


\section*{Abstract}
\begin{itemize}
\item {\small\verb|\cite{Chandra:81}|}   $\rightarrow$   \cite{Chandra:81}.\\end{itemize}
\item {\small\verb|\shortcite{Chandra:81}|}   $\rightarrow$   \shortcite{Chandra:81}.
\item {\small\verb|\newcite{Chandra:81}|} $\rightarrow$ Chandra et al., (1989)
\end{itemize}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{ref.bib}

\end{document}
```

ref.bib

```
@article{Chandra:81,
    author = {Ashok K. Chandra and Dexter C. Kozen and Larry J. Stockmeyer},
    year = "1981",
    title = {Alternation},
    journal = {Journal of the Association for Computing Machinery},
    volume = "28",
    number = "1",
    pages = "114--133"
}
```

The last row (above References) is my desired citation style:

[image]

Comment: Please take a look at the `apacite` documentation. It provides citing commands for all of these cases. I recommend using the `natbibapa` option to the package and using the `natbib` versions of them. There's a summary here too: [What is the relationship between natbib, apacite package, and apa document class?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263793)

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks. Found the answer in the documentation. `\citeA` and `\shortciteA` will do it.

Comment: @AlanMunn Want to add an answer?