# How to write "(e.g. Surname, 2018)" with apacite?

Tags: bibtex, citing, apacite

I am trying to write: "(e.g. Surname, 2018)" using apacite package.

I have tried `(e.g. \cite{surname2018}})`  (too many brackets),  `\cite{surname2018}` (does not have e.g.) , and `(e.g. \citeA{surname2018}}` but it still does not work.

What should I do in this case?

Comment: Welcome! Does `(e.g.~\citet{surname2018} )` work?

Comment: In `natbib` package `\citep` has two optional parameters for prefix and postfix, but this won't help you, probably.

Comment: Thank you, marmot! I tried that and it comes out as an error (using citet).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `apacite` package supports two sorts of citation commands, its own version, or the `natbib` versions (loaded with the `natbibapa` package option.)

The citation commands support both a pre-note and a post-note.  The basic syntax is:

```
\cite<pre-note>[post-note]{citekey}
```

where `\cite` gives you *(pre-note Author, Year, post-note)*, `\citeA` gives you *pre-note Author (Year, post-note)*.

So to get your example, you would use:

```
\cite<e.g.>{citekey}.
```

If you are using the `natbibapa` option, the command syntax is slightly different:

```
\cite[pre-note][post-note]{citekey}
```

yields *pre-note Author (year,post-note)* while

```
\citep[pre-note][post-note]{citekey}
```

yields *(pre-note Author, Year, post-note)*.

Since square brackets are used to delimit both the pre-note and the post-note, you need to provide an empty post-note to get a pre-note only.  So your example would be:

```
\citep[e.g.][]{citekey}
```

You can find the full set of citation commands in the `apacite` documentation, or for a quick summary see: [What is the relationship between natbib, apacite package, and apa document class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263793/2693).