# How come citation of author and page number using apacite does not work?

Tags: citing, apacite

I have recently been asked to use APA referencing and want to include specific page numbers for a book reference. I know that the apacite package allows this for example by typing `\cite[pp.56-58]{Author2016}`. This should come out like **(Author 2016, pp.56-58)**. In stead it comes out like **(?, ?)pp.56-58]Author2016**.

I am using TexMaker with bibtex and the list of references compiles fine when I don't include specific page numbers but simply fails to recognise it as a reference when I do.

What seems to be the problem?

Here's the document setup I use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
        \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}                           
        \usepackage{hyperref}                                       
        \usepackage{apacite}                                    
        \usepackage[english]{babel}                             
        \usepackage[footnote,marginclue,draft,danish,silent,nomargin]{fixme}    
        \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}                           
        \usepackage{float}                                      
        \usepackage{gensymb}                                    
        \usepackage[strings]{underscore}                        
        \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
        \graphicspath{{Figure/}}                                
        \setlength\bibitemsep{1\baselineskip}

... according to \cite[pp.56-58]{Author2006}.

        \bibliographystyle{apacite}
        \newpage
        \bibliography{Bib}
        \end{document}
```

Comment: Have you thought about using a more modern package?

Comment: @Johannes_B There's nothing wrong with `apacite`. It works well and is quite up-to-date. The problem is that the for the `\cite[]{}` syntax you need to load the package with the `natbibapa` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `apacite` package supports two forms of citation commands, "classic", and `natbib`.  The syntax you are using for your citation is the `natbib` syntax, so you need to load the `apacite` package with the `natbibapa` option:

```
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
```

See the following question (or the `apacite` documentation) for more details:

- [How to write "(e.g. Surname, 2018)" with apacite?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/408564/2693)