# errors in apacite.sty on running pdflatex

Tags: errors

[image]

```
 \documentclass{interact}
 \usepackage{epstopdf}% To incorporate .eps illustrations using PDFLaTeX, etc.
 \usepackage{subfig}% Support for small, `sub' figures and tables
 %\usepackage[nolists,tablesfirst]{endfloat}% To `separate' figures and tables 
 %from text if required
 %\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}% To produce a `double spaced' document if 
 %required
 %\setlength\parindent{24pt}% To increase paragraph indentation when line spacing 
 %is doubled

 \usepackage[longnamesfirst,sort,comma,authoryear]{natbib}% Citation support 
 %using natbib.sty
 \bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}% Citation support using natbib.sty
 \renewcommand\bibfont{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}% To set the list of 
 %references in 10 point font using natbib.sty

 %\usepackage[natbibapa,nodoi]{apacite}% Citation support using apacite.sty. 
 %Commands using natbib.sty MUST be deactivated first!
 %\setlength\bibhang{12pt}% To set the indentation in the list of references 
 %using apacite.sty. Commands using natbib.sty MUST be deactivated first!
 %\renewcommand\bibliographytypesize{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}% To set the 
 %list of references in 10 point font using apacite.sty. Commands using 
 %natbib.sty 
 %\MUST be deactivated first!

 \theoremstyle{plain}% Theorem-like structures provided by amsthm.sty
 \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[natbibapa,nodoi]{apacite}
\setlength\bibhang{12pt}
\renewcommand\bibliographytypesize{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}
%\usepackage{cite}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}


\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{thesis}

\end{document}
```

Comment: everytime pdflatex is being run...apacite.sty opens with almost 400+ errors..

Answer (score 2):

Just made these changes and doesn't give any more errors:

First got rid your `documentclass` (replaced by `article`, but not asking to do it... just could not -didn't want- to search for it). I had to get rid (comment out) the `teoremstyle` too ... but if it is defined in there you could use it.

Second got rid of the `\usepackage{epstopdf}` ... If you really need it, add it, but add `graphicx` or something before it.

Third loaded `apacite` before `natbib` to get rid some remaining errors.

Fourth according to this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263800/120578
I had to remove the options from `natbib` package while loading. (Consider of not mixing the packages because there is not a real need to do that -Read that post-)

The following code (with the above changes) doesn't give errors.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}% To incorporate .eps illustrations using PDFLaTeX, etc.
\usepackage{subfig}% Support for small, `sub' figures and tables
%\usepackage[nolists,tablesfirst]{endfloat}% To `separate' figures and tables 
%from text if required
%\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}% To produce a `double spaced' document if 
%required
%\setlength\parindent{24pt}% To increase paragraph indentation when line spacing 
%is doubled
\usepackage[natbibapa,nodoi]{apacite}
\usepackage{natbib}% Citation support 

%using natbib.sty
\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}% Citation support using natbib.sty
\renewcommand\bibfont{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}% To set the list of 
%references in 10 point font using natbib.sty

%\usepackage[natbibapa,nodoi]{apacite}% Citation support using apacite.sty. 
%Commands using natbib.sty MUST be deactivated first!
%\setlength\bibhang{12pt}% To set the indentation in the list of references 
%using apacite.sty. Commands using natbib.sty MUST be deactivated first!
%\renewcommand\bibliographytypesize{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}% To set the 
%list of references in 10 point font using apacite.sty. Commands using 
%natbib.sty 
%\MUST be deactivated first!

%\theoremstyle{plain}% Theorem-like structures provided by amsthm.sty
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

%\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

%\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\setlength\bibhang{12pt}
\renewcommand\bibliographytypesize{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}
%\usepackage{cite}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}


\begin{document}
TEST
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{thesis}

\end{document}
```