# Bibliography style `apalike` missing the paranthesis

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, apa-style

I am using:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

However, when I use for example:

```
\cite{test}
```

I should be getting my reference within `()`, i.e. parenthesis right? But they seem to have vanished! I am now getting them without the parenthesis. What would be
the source of the problem?

Only when I use `\citet*{test}` the `()` should disappear, as in an in text citation.

**EDIT:**

Now I tried using `\citep{}` and **it seems to work!** I wonder if I say `\cite{}` shouldn't I be getting the parenthesis? Why do I need to specifically call it using `\citep{}`??

Comment: Have you tried `\autocite` ?

Comment: Now I tried using `\citep{}` and it seems to work! I wonder if I say `\cite{}` shouldn't I be getting the parenthesis? Why do I need to specifically call it using `\citep{}`??

Comment: Right, I haven't really been using `natbib`, as when I started using LaTeX, I was told my many sources that `BibLaTeX` combined with the `biber`-backend was the way to go. You could possibly have a look at [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `natbib` package provides two main citation commands:

- `\citet` for in-text citations.  This yields *Author (Year)*
- `\citep` for parenthesized citations. This yields *(Author, Year)*

The standard APA citation style for in-text citations puts only the year in parentheses, and `natbib` reflects this by making `\cite` a synonym for `\citet` (which is the command for in-text citation).

For citations that are themselves within parentheses, which get a different style, the `natbib` command is `\citep`, as you have discovered.

The use of `\cite` in `natbib` is only provided as a convenience for compatibility with the standard `\cite` command.

If you need a truly conforming APA bibliography, I recommend using `biblatex-apa` which is kept up-to-date.  See:

- [What is the relationship between natbib, apacite package, and apa document class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263793/2693)
- [Perfect APA Style Bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/191404/2693)